# Which is better in PHP, Static Variable or Private Variable?

Tags: php, class, variables, static, private

I noticed two ways in PHP to do the same thing. Can you tell me which way is a better programming practice?

In the first example, I use a private variable on the class. On the second example, I use a static variable in a class method.

```
class Test {
  private $_myvar;
  public function getVar(){
    if (!isset($this->_myvar)) {
      $this->_myvar = "test\n";
    }
    return $this->_myvar;
  }
}
$oTest = new Test();
echo $oTest->getVar(); // sets var first time and returns it
echo $oTest->getvar(); // pulls from cache
```

Or:

```
class Test {
  public function getVar(){
    static $myvar;
    if (!isset($myvar)) {
      $myvar = "test\n";
    }
    return $myvar;
  }
}
$oTest = new Test();
echo $oTest->getVar(); // sets var first time and returns it
echo $oTest->getvar(); // pulls from cache
```

Comment: in your first example it shouldn't it say $this->_myvar not $_myvar?

Comment: The "private" part makes no difference; the same behaviour is there with public and protected class properties as well.

Comment: @El Yobo, right, but having an accessor for a public variable would be silly. :)

Comment: @bumperbox - my bad -- typo. Thanks! I'll edit.

Comment: It would be silly, yes :) I'm just pointing out that the "private" doesn't change the behaviour here.  It would, for example, make sense to have an accessor for a protected variable; but whether it makes sense or not the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the class property (be it public, private or protected), the variable is accessible to other parts of the class.

With the static variable, it is only visible to that method of the class.

I would suggest using the class property (but probably not private, which I generally don't find much use for; protected is normally a better idea) as it's easier for testing later; you can't do anything to unset, alter or check the static variable.

I see some possible confusion in the other answers here between *static variables* and *static class properties*.  PHP uses the same modifier, but the behaviour is quite different; an example follows.

```
<?php
class Foo {
   // Static class property
   public static $bar = 'bar';

   public function blarg() {
      static $bar;
      if (empty($bar)) {
         $bar = 'blarg';
      }
      return $bar;
   }
}
```

In the above example the static class property can be accessed using `Foo::$bar` (or `self::$bar` within the class and `static::$bar` in PHP 5.3); the static variable *cannot* and is only visible inside the function `blarg()`.

Comment: I realize it was a bizarre question. You'd have to see the code I was working in to realize the context. But you made me realize that, yeah, static vars are accessible only to the class method. Actually, only one class method needed access to that variable, anyway. And in another section of my code on this project I have -- it made sense to use the private (now protected) var because multiple class methods needed to access it.

Comment: See also Orbling's comment below, which provides some further details about the weird (and, to my mind, highly undesirable) behaviour of static variables in object methods.

Answer (score 15):

That is like saying which room is better the Kitchen or the Bathroom, they are both rooms, but they have different functions.

A `static` variable is the same in multiple objects.

An instance variable, declared via `private` above is particular to a given object.

Note that `private` is an access modifier, `static` is not, a variable can be both.

In the location you have your `static` variable, within the function, it is not a class/object variable at all, but a traditional function-level `static` variable, which will be single-instanced across all calls to the function, making it similar to a class-level `static` variable, but only accessible within the method it is defined within.

Comment: I think you're confusing static class properties with static variables here; PHP uses the same modifier, but the behaviour is quite different.

Comment: Not static in this context. Like in C++, PHP static variables are specific to the function of the instance of the class.

Comment: @aharon i just tried this and i am pretty sure the static var persists across multiple objects.

Comment: @El Yobo: No, I'm fully aware of the difference between the different uses of static, even more so since v5.3 where there is a further use.  I thought about mentioning that, but thought it would just confuse someone obviously new to this.

Comment: @aharon: Are you sure that is true in PHP?  I have not tested, Sabeen says it does.

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day; Sabeen is correct, the static variable in the method *is* shared across objects.  That's got to be the source of some really confusing bugs! Even more reason not to use it; modifying it in one instance magically changes it in another.

Comment: @El Yobo: Aye, thought as much (yet I still have a downvote).  I would expect it to work that way in PHP, as there is no mention that it would work differently within a class, as opposed to anywhere else.  Very bad practice to use it within a class though, as it is designed for non-OOP usage.

Comment: My mistake then, that's really weird. PHP… @Orbling, could you edit your answer so I can undownvote you?

Comment: Not my downvote :)  It's very surprising behaviour to me; it seems to completely break the normal scoping rules via some sort of quantum entanglement of variables!

Comment: @El Yobo: Well scoping rules and PHP is a bit of a black-art at the best of times.  The trouble with PHP is a vastly altered language that retains an immense amount of legacy.  Few other languages have altered so much over time.  The trick is not to use the legacy stuff (at least not at the same time as modern facilities!).

Comment: @El Yobo: Using a static variable in a class method was how you did static class variables in PHP 4. It was a little clunky, and possibly an unintended side-effect, but it worked.

Comment: @staticsan, I never did OO when I worked with PHP4 :)  However, how did that work?  As noted, the variable is still only visible within that function, albeit in multiple instances, so it would have still had vastly more limited usefulness; it can't be accessed from elsewhere in the class, nor from other classes, nor without instantiating something.

Comment: I pushed the boundaries with OO in PHP4. :-) It was perfectly legal for an instance method to have static variables because they were implemented using a kind of name mangling with a hidden first parameter. And you *could* call such a method statically (`class::func()`), if it never referenced `$this`. Like I said, clunky. But it worked.

Comment: @staticsan: Like I said, PHP has altered lots, then altered some more.  It's amazing it has any consistency at all.

Answer (score 4):

Neither is "better". It would be like asking whether a screwdriver is better than a tenon saw.

The private variable in your first example will only be available to that instance of the class (although only to its methods). Create a new instance, and the variable can and will have a different value.

The static variable in your second example will be available to all instances of that class, admittedly only in that method. But set it one instance, and a second instance will see the same value.